# How to write a turing machine program for any given problem?

Tags: turing-machines, turing-recognizable

I'm learning about Turing machine program,i want to know how we write a Turing machine program about any given problem, like a string is accepted by Turing machine, program (for a Single Tape Turing Machine) that checks if a binary
number on the tape is an even number  etc

Comment: I am afraid there is no panacea or general solution to this problem; it really boils down to what you are trying to solve. I imagine a trial-and-error process with incremental corrections is the way to go. The more you practise, the better you get at it.

Comment: The tricky thing about answering this question is that "how to write a Turing machine program about any given problem" is quite literally the definition of the entire discipline of programming.

Comment: Are you asking about how, given a program in some language like C (i.e. a language that uses variables, arrays, etc.), to translate it to a Turing machine (which does not use variables and array, but uses states and the tape)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about an algorithm to solve the problem.

Then write a Turing-machine that implements this algorithm.

For instance, checking if a binary number is even can be done by examining its rightmost bit.

That gives you an algorithm: First you look for the rightmost bit, then when you have found it, you check whether it is 0 or 1.

So you can make a Turing-machine with four states: "have not found the right-most bit yet", "have found the right-most bit", "the right-most bit is 0", "the right-most bit is 1". Then write the transitions between these states.

Answer (score 0):

Let me narrow down your question: is it always possible to write a Turing Machine that solves any **mathematical** problem? We can make this more precise by reviewing some terms:

- Let $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}.$ Denote $\Sigma^*$ as the set of binary strings (including the empty string). A **language** $L$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*.$ (You can use any finite set for $\Sigma$. The choice is arbitrary, but many texts I’ve read frequently use it).
- Let $M$ be a Turing Machine, and let $L(M)$ be the set of all strings accepted by $M.$

  - $M$ **recognizes** a language $L$ if $L = L(M).$
  - $M$ **decides** $L$ if it recognizes $L$ and halts on all inputs.
- A language is **Turing-recognizable** if it is recognized by a Turing Machine, and **Turing-decidable** if it is decided by a Turing Machine. For readability, I will drop the prefix.

Now we can rephrase your question: is every language decidable?

The answer is **no.** One famous example is Alan Turing’s Halting Problem: determine whether a Turing Machine halts or not on a given input. You can find more details in [his paper](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Erobins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf), where he first introduced Turing Machines. (If you are interested in why he wrote this paper, I would suggest looking into the [Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem), a major mathematical issue from the 20th century).

Note that you can recognize the Halting Problem. Roughly speaking, you can write a Turing Machine $M’$ that monitors $M$: if $M$ accepts or rejects an input, so will $M’.$ But if $M$ never halts on some input (goes into an infinite loop), so will $M’.$ However, there are languages that can’t be recognized by a Turing Machine. For example, you can make an unrecognizable language through diagonalization (see [these slides](https://people.computing.clemson.edu/%7Egoddard/texts/theoryOfComputation/14b.pdf) from Clemson University).

We can strengthen this result as [Rice’s Theorem][4]: every non-trivial property of a Turing machine is undecidable. A property is trivial if it is true of all Turing machines or none of them. In particular, not all Turing machines are recognizers for some fixed language $L,$ so we cannot decide this, in general.

With all of that said, there are many instances where we *can* write down a Turing Machine. These include some important computational classes:

- Any regular language/regex. This includes Stef’s example.
- Any context free grammar. This includes parsing *most* programming languages.
- Any polynomial time running algorithm.
- And so on.

In your original question, I suspect you wanted to know whether *humans* can write down a Turing Machine for some problem. This is really a question about what humans can compute, which is an issue for philosophy. For that, I would suggest looking into the [Church Turing thesis.][5]

[4]: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#:~:text=Rice's%20theorem%20asserts%20that%20it,or%20false%20of%20all%20programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=Rice%27s%20theorem%20asserts%20that%20it,or%20false%20of%20all%20programs)).
[5]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis